# How to combine ODA File Converter with OGR (GDAL) so that dwg is a format option

Tags: gdal, ogr, dwg

0

I have downloaded ogr/gdal with QGIS 3.34.1 and I have downloaded the ODA file converter zip file from https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/oda_file_converter

However, I am not sure how to combine the two so that DWG format is an option for a ogr2ogr command. I've tried looking at the documentation on the gdal website https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/oda.html#vector-oda but I can't understand the process.

Is anyone able to advise me on how I can achieve getting DWG in my list of OGR formats? For reference, I am using Windows